# sbin/start-stop-daemon not able to start python - ubuntu docker container

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I have a simple python script which I want to start a daemon-service in background in docker container

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon --start  --user root --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/lock/subsys/my-application.pid --exec 'python /opt/app/uc/monitor/bin/my-application.py'
```

when I execute this command in a shell I get

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon: unable to stat //python /opt/app/uc/monitor/bin/my-application.py (No such file or directory)
```

However when execute just the below command in shell it works

```
python /opt/app/uc/monitor/bin/my-application.py
```

I'm sure the python is installed and all the links have been setup.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Docker is not a virtual machine.   There is no upstart, and therefore no start-stop-daemons.   Checkout runit or supervisor if you must.   Or you could stick to the one process/one container 'best practice'.

Comment: I figured that and created a launcher script ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message implies that `start-stop-daemon` is looking for a file to open (the `stat` operation is a check before it opens the file) and treating your `'python ... '` argument as if it was a file.

See [this example](https://gist.github.com/alobato/1968852) which confirms this.  You may need to read the [man page for start-stop-daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html), for your Ubuntu version, to check what a valid command would be for your setup.

Simplest solution is probably to create a shell script (say `/opt/app/uc/monitor/bin/run-my-application.sh`), and put this into it:

```
#!/bin/bash
python /opt/app/uc/monitor/bin/my-application.py
```

Be sure to do `chmod +x` on this file.  If python is not found, use `which python` to find the path to `python` and use that in the script.

Now try:

```
/sbin/start-stop-daemon --start  --user root --make-pidfile --pidfile /var/lock/subsys/my-application.pid --exec '/opt/app/uc/monitor/bin/run-my-application.sh'
```